# How to catch HystrixTimeout Exception in Zuul

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, netflix-zuul, hystrix

when web service does not respond in a time(timeout) and throwing HystrixTimeout Exception, i want to catch HystrixTimeout Exception in ZuulFilter. how can i handle that?

Note: in ZuulFilter, i catch my custom exception. Like a below code

```
@Override
public Object run() {
    final RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
    final Object throwable = context.get(THROWABLE_KEY);

    if (throwable instanceof ZuulException) {
        ZuulException zuulException = (ZuulException) throwable;
        
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this problem was not my real problem. firstly, i understood this. Because my app throwing SocketTimeoutException as a base exceptio. So if i can catch SocketTimeoutException, i can handle this problem but for this solution i need to get exceptions' cause of cause. I wrote a method like a below code.

```
private Throwable findRightException(Throwable th) {
        Throwable throwable = th;
        if (throwable.getCause() == null || throwable.getCause() instanceof SocketTimeoutException) {
            return throwable.getCause();
        }
        return findRightException(throwable.getCause());
```

Comment: Because as i sad, the main exception is SocketTimeoutException